# Fragment set element visibility not working correctly

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment that is set up, depending on the page the fragment should show or hide a number of elements within it:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_install__ubuntu, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.top_text);
            TextView middleText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.middle_text);
            TextView bottomText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_text);

            Button imageDownload = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_DownloadImage);
            Button vnc = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_DownloadVNC);
            Button terminal = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_DownloadTerminal);


            int pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

            switch (pageNumber) {
                case 0:
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    middleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bottomText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    vnc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    terminal.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                case 1:
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    middleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bottomText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    vnc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    terminal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                case 2:
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    middleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bottomText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    vnc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    terminal.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                case 3:
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    middleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bottomText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    vnc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    terminal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            return rootView;
        }
    }
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "1";
                case 1:
                    return "2";
                case 2:
                    return "3";
                case 3:
                    return "4";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

However this doesn't seem to be working correctly, for example with the above code the last fragment shows all the elements instead of the 2nd fragment as it should be.

What is the proper way to modify the fragment view depending on its position?

Comment: You forgot to add break statement on each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot to add **break;** after every switch case

```
            switch (pageNumber) {
                case 0:
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    middleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bottomText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    vnc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    terminal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;


                case 1:
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    middleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bottomText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    vnc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    terminal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    middleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bottomText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    vnc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    terminal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    middleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bottomText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    vnc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    terminal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
            }
```